# Can't get my program to wait gives my white screen! Java

Tags: java, grid, jframe

Hi I'm a little new to java and I was creating this pattern game. What I want the program to do is it displays a pattern on a 4x4 grid then wait for a few seconds for the user to memorize the pattern then display a blank input screen for the user to input the pattern. The problem I have run into is that the JFrame appears that is supposed to have the pattern but the JFrame shows a blank screen waits then shows the blank input screen. Thanks in advance.

```
package game;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import menu.menu;

public class Game implements Properties, Runnable
{
    public static JFrame gf = new JFrame();
    public static int height = 800;
    public static int width = 600;
    public static int gsize = 4;
    public static int order =1;
    public static Dimension size = new Dimension(height,width);
    public static menu Menu = new menu();
    public static GridLayout Ggrid = new GridLayout(gsize,gsize);
    public static void setup() {
        menu.close();
        gf.dispose();
        gf = new JFrame();
        gf.setLocation(300,100);
        gf.setSize(size);
        gf.setResizable(false);
        gf.setLayout(Ggrid);
        gf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gf.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void blank()
    {
        for (int a =0;a<4;a++)
        {
            for (int b =0;b<4;b++)
            {
                JButton button = new JButton("");
                gf.add(button);
            }
        }
    }

    public static int flag =0;
    public static void gameStart()
    {

        getpattern();
        try
        {
            t.sleep(3000);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

        setup();
        blank();
        }
    public static void getpattern()
    {
        if (order == 1)
            {
            for (int a=0;a<4;a++)
            {
                for(int b=0;b<4;b++)
                {
                    if (handlebars[a][b] == 1)
                    {
                    JButton button = new JButton("X");
                    gf.add(button);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        JButton button = new JButton("");
                        gf.add(button);
                    }
                    flag =1;
                }
            }
            }
        if (order == 2)
            {
            for (int a=0;a<4;a++)
            {
                for(int b=0;b<4;b++)
                {
                    if (ys[a][b] == 1)
                    {
                    JButton button = new JButton("X");
                    gf.add(button);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        JButton button = new JButton("");
                        gf.add(button);
                    }
                }
            }
            }
        if (order == 3)
        {
        for (int a=0;a<4;a++)
        {
            for(int b=0;b<4;b++)
            {
                if (spaceShip[a][b] == 1)
                {
                JButton button = new JButton("X");
                gf.add(button);
                }
                else
                {
                    JButton button = new JButton("");
                    gf.add(button);
                }
            }
        }
        }   if (order == 4)
        {
        for (int a=0;a<4;a++)
        {
            for(int b=0;b<4;b++)
            {
                if (flock[a][b] == 1)
                {
                JButton button = new JButton("X");
                gf.add(button);
                }
                else
                {
                    JButton button = new JButton("");
                    gf.add(button);
                }
            }
        }
        }   if (order == 5)
        {
        for (int a=0;a<4;a++)
        {
            for(int b=0;b<4;b++)
            {
                if (percent[a][b] == 1)
                {
                JButton button = new JButton("X");
                gf.add(button);
                }
                else
                {
                    JButton button = new JButton("");
                    gf.add(button);
                }
            }
        }
        }
        if (order == 6)
        {
        for (int a=0;a<4;a++)
        {
            for(int b=0;b<4;b++)
            {
                if (square[a][b] == 1)
                {
                JButton button = new JButton("X");
                gf.add(button);
                }
                else
                {
                    JButton button = new JButton("");
                    gf.add(button);
                }
            }
        }
        }
        gf.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static Thread t = new Thread();

    @Override
    public void run() {

        t=new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically what is not working is

```
 public static void getpattern()
    {
        if (order == 1)
            {
```

...

```
                if (handlebars[a][b] == 1)
```

**update**

In games start call Thread.sleep(3000); and print out any exceptions.

If you comment out

```
setup();
blank();
```

does the grid appear correctly?

Comment: handlebars,ys,spaceship,flock,percent,square are all initialised in another class"properties" which this class implements

Comment: well your `getpattern()` method will only get called for `order == 1`

Comment: well I plan on after the person gets the pattern it will do'order++;' then display the next pattern

Comment: well I looked on the web and this looked to be the most frequently given answer to others problems so im not entirely clear on how ever thing works with threads and stuff

Comment: I suggest that you either use a debugger to step through your step, or to insert `print` statements in relevant parts E.g. `System.out.println (handlebars[a][b]);`

Comment: Ok I have checked out the handlebar pattern it works it is just i display it on a screen then i want the program to wait 3 seconds then close that frame open a new one where they could input the pattern and it gives me a white screen instead of the pattern

Comment: Updated my answer for you

Comment: What happens is that it opens a new frame that is white then after three seconds displays correct pattern

Comment: OK, the control will not be given back to the main thread until the method returns, so the original data will not be displayed.  Try kicking off a new thread (that sleeps) and blanks out the grid.

Comment: Thanks any hints on being able to do that I am kinda new to threads

Comment: You may want to search for more information but maybe the easiest way wouldbe to create a new class (implements Runnable) implement run (this will run your blank code).  This new class will to be passed the necessary parameters before you call the start method - see http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-threads-tutorial